# Counting Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Been wrestling with the following counting question for about an hour. I will explain my reasoning for counting in the question and I request any BETTER WAY to make this calculation or corrections if my counting is wrong.

"If each coded item in a catalog begins with 3 distinct letters followed by 4 distinct   nonzero digits, find the probability of randomly selecting one of these coded items with the first letter a vowel and the last digit even."

I first calculate the sample space:

```
26 * 25 * 24 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6
= 47,174,400
```

This is done using the simple "placeholder" technique for counting.

Now I must calculate the special case such that the first letter is a vowel and the last digit even. The "placeholder" technique confuses me here.

```
5 * 25 * 24 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 4 = 6,048,000
```

So probability  is 6048000/47,174,400.

I can't  help but think this is wrong. What about the case where the code has a vowel BEFORE the last vowel, for example. Does this not make the calculation the following:

```
 5 * 25 * 24 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 3
```

Because one vowel has already been seleccted BEFORE the last vowel... there are fewer choices.

Should I need to add up all the permutations in which there is a vowel previous to the last vowel? That seems agonizing... what theorems and rules can I get both the **correct** and **easiest path** to the answer?

After some Google-ry, I found this explanation for the solution in a textbook. How do they get this? What witchery is this? Why is it so different than the other answers?:

[image]

Comment: Choose the even number first, then select the other numbers.

Comment: The textbook's answer seems to be wrong. $|A| = {5 \choose 1} 2! {25 \choose 2} 3! {8 \choose 3} {4 \choose 1} $ = 4,032,000.

Comment: @Shitikanth Perhaps. The textbook says it is C(23, 2) instead of C(25,2). Is there any reason that it should be C(23, 2) as oppose to C(25,2), I wonder.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure their solution is incorrect. For this question, there is no need to count at all, see my answer.

Comment: Hey I think I've got an idea: Make it 5 * 25 * 24 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 5. Basically we are counting the 4 digits reverse, so it's easier acting like the even digit is first rather than last.

Answer (score 3):

Your calculation for letters is just fine. I think you confused yourself with the rest of your question. Recall, we have $3$ distinct *letters* **followed by** $4$ distinct ***numbers***. So vowels need not come into play at the end of the sequence. If you meant "even numbers": we can choose to fill the even number first (even though it appears last), leaving $8$ remaining numbers distinct from that the even number chosen to fill the second "digit" slot, then $7$ numbers to fill the third "digit" slot, then $6$ for the last digit. Overall,  the combinations with first letter a vowel, last number an even number is $$5\cdot 25\cdot 24 \cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 4 = 4,032,000$$

So the probability of selecting one of the desired combinations from among all the combinations in the sample space is given by $$\dfrac{4,032,000}{47,174,400} = \dfrac{10}{117}$$

Comment: This seems to apply to the calculation for the sample space. That portion may well be correct, but does the calculation for the case with the "first letter is a vowel and the last digit even" seem correct? I can't help but shake the feeling that I am not counting it correctly.

Comment: But the case of last digit even is overcounted, as there could be an even among the first three.

Comment: @RossMillikan, there is no requirement that the last digit be the ONLY even digit.  We pick one of the 4 possible even digits for the last spot, then we pick one of the 8 remaining non-zero, not-previously-selected digits for spot 1, then one of the 7 remaining for spot 2, and one of the 6 remaining for spot 3.  So there is no over-counting.

Comment: @Hellion:  That is correct.  At the time I made the comment, it was $9*8*7*4$

Comment: +1 but I don't like probability, Amy ;-)

Comment: @amWhy +1 for you.I agree with Babak S. , I don't like probability too. :D

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal E$ be the event that the first character is a vowel and $\mathcal F$ be the event that the last digit is even.

$\begin{align*}
P[\mathcal E \cap \mathcal F] &= P[\mathcal E]P[\mathcal F | \mathcal E]\\
&= P[\mathcal E]P[\mathcal F] &\text{(the events are clearly independent)}\\
&= \frac{5}{26} \times \frac 4 9\\
&= \frac {10}{117}
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you did fine with the letters.  You have five ways to select the first vowel, then 25 and 24 for the next two letters because you don't care whether they are vowels or consonants.  For the numbers, the problem is you don't know how many evens were chosen in the first three.  It is better to select the last digit first, as you know four evens are available, so the count of numbers is $4*8*7*6$

When you say a vowel before the last vowel, is that just two vowels?  You have four choices for the layout of vowels and consonants:  VVC, VCV, CVV, VVV.  Assuming they are all acceptable, the first three all have the same number of combinations, so we can calculate the first and multiply by 3:  $3*5*4*21$, where the $5,4$ are the number of vowels available and the $21$ is the number of consonants.  VVV is then $5*4*3$, so the total number of letter orders is $3*5*4*21+5*4*3=1320$.  If we just did $3*5*4*24$ (figuring that we had $24$ letters available after we picked the two vowels) we would count VVV three times, once for making each letter the "wild card".

Comment: I see you are considering the case I mentione - rad! But I don't follow 3 * 5 * 4 * 24? Where do you get that? What does that mean for the probability calculation?

Comment: See my update.  There was an error.